# How to efficiently parse out number from a string in Shell?

Tags: shell, parsing

For example if I have the following string:

```
I ate [ 6 ] chicken wings and [ 5 ] dishes of salad today.
```

I want to parse out `6` and `5` from this string to store to two variables `A` and `B` respectively. I am thinking of using `[` and `]` as the delimiters, and then narrow down to delimiting with spaces.. I am looking for simpler solutions to this. Thanks.

Comment: Tell us the bigger picture - what are you planning to do next with the digits? And in what language? I really wouldn't worry about delimiters for now anyway, they can be picked up easily enough with a regular expression without delimiters. See \d.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It's in shellscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using "sed" to replace all non-digits with spaces and let the shell use the space as the separator:

```
LINE="hi 1 there, 65 apples and 73 pears"
for i in $(echo $LINE | sed -e "s/[^0-9]/ /g" )
do
   echo $i
done
1
65
73
```

Of course you can assign "i" to any variable you want as well, or you can create an array of your numbers and print them out:

```
LINE="hi 1 there 65 apples and 73 pears"
nums=($(echo hi 1 there 65 apples and 73 pears | sed -e "s/[^0-9]/ /g" ))
echo ${nums[@]}
1 65 73
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -o` with a perl regex:

```
line="I ate [ 6 ] chicken wings and [ 5 ] dishes of salad today."
n=( $( echo "$line" | grep -oP '(?<=\[ )\d+(?= \])' ) )
a=${n[0]} b=${n[1]}
```

You can work with the `n` array directly too:

```
for num in "${n[@]}"; do echo $num; done
```